# How to get CMake to use existing Makefile?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have an existing project (`wvdial`) that has a working makefile. I'm trying to integrate it into our main build process which uses CMake.  Can anyone advise on how to do this? I made an attempt below based on some of the other projects we build but the makefile is never called.  All I want to do is call the makefile for wvdial and include the binary in the `.deb` package we build.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

    SET(COMPONENT_NAME roots-vendor-wvdial)

    SET(DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION 1.6.1)

    SET(WVDIAL_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(WVDIAL_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
    SET(WVDIAL_INSTALLED ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        wvdial ALL
        DEPENDS ${WVDIAL_INSTALLED}
    )

    IF (${ROOTS_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE} STREQUAL "armhf")
       SET(TARGET_FLAG "--host=arm-linux-gnueabihf")
    ENDIF()

    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${WVDIAL_BINARY_DIR}
        OUTPUT ${WVDIAL_INSTALLED}
        COMMAND env CXXFLAGS=${ROOTS_COMPILER_FLAGS} ./configure ${TARGET_FLAG} ${ROOTS_HOST_OPTION}
        COMMAND make
        COMMENT "Building wvdial"
        VERBATIM
    )


    INSTALL(
        FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wvdial
        DESTINATION usr/local/bin
        COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_NAME}
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ WORLD_EXECUTE WORLD_READ
    )

    DEFINE_DEBIAN_PACKAGE(
        NAME ${COMPONENT_NAME}
        CONTROL_TEMPLATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/control
        CHANGELOG_TEMPLATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/changelog
    )
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject) module.

This will add a dummy target to your CMake project that is responsible for building the dependency. The command is quite complex and supports a lot of stuff that you probably won't need in your case. Kitware (the company behind CMake) did a [nice post called *Building External Projects with CMake 2.8*](https://blog.kitware.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/kitware_quarterly1009.pdf) a while back explaining the basic use of that command.