# CMake: compilation speed when including external makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I have a c++ cmake project. In this project I build (among other) one example, where I need to use another project, call it `Foo`. This `Foo` project does not offer a cmake build system. Instead, it has a pre-made Makefile.custom.in. In order to build an executable that uses `Foo`'s features, one needs to copy this makefile in his project, and modify it (typically setting the SOURCES variable and a few compiler flags). Basically, this Makefile ends up having the sources for your executable and also all the source files for the `Foo` project. You will not end up using `Foo` as a library.

Now, this is a design I don't like, but for the sake of the question, let's say we stick with it.

To create my example inside my cmake build I added a custom target:

```
CONFIGURE_FILE( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Makefile.custom.in Makefile.custom)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(my_target COMMAND $(MAKE) -f Makefile.custom
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

This works. I can specify some variables to cmake, which get resolved in the call to `CONFIGURE_FILE`, and I end up with a working Makefile.custom. Then, invoking `make my_target` from the build directory, I can build the executable. I can even add it to the `all` target (to save me the effort of typing `make my_target`) with

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(my_target PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL FALSE)
```

Sweet. However, cmake appears to assign a single job to the custom target, slowing down my compilation time (the `Foo` source folder contains a couple dozens cpp files). On top of that, the `make clean` target does not forward to the custom makefile. I end up having to add another target:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(really-clean COMMAND "$(MAKE)" clean
                  COMMAND "$(MAKE)" -f Makefile.custom clean
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

which, unlike `my_target` with `all`, I can't include in the `clean` target (can I?).

Now, I know that a cleaner solution would be to have the `Foo` project be built as an external project, and then link to it. However, I've been 'recommended' to use their Makefile.custom.in makefile, modifying the few lines I need (adding my sources, specifying compiler flags, and few other minor modifications). So, regardless of how neat and clean this design pattern is, my questions are:

- is there a way to tell cmake that make should use more than 1 job when making the target my_target?
- is there a cleaner way to include a pre-existing makefile in a cmake project? Note that I don't want (can't?) use `Foo` as a library (and link against it). I want (need?) to compile it together with my executable using a makefile not generated by cmake (well, cmake can help a bit, through `CONFIGURE_FILE`, by resolving some variables, but that's it).

Note: I am aware of ExternalProject (as suggested also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352528/1093346) answer), but I think it's not exactly what I need here (since it would build `Foo` and then use it as a library). Also, both my project and `Foo` are written exclusively in C++ (not sure this matter at all).

I hope the question makes sense (regardless of how ugly/annoying/unsatisfactory the resulting design would be).

Edit: I am using cmake version 3.5.2

Comment: If build time matters, consider switching to Ninja. That would help in your case, too.

Comment: I thought about ninja. I did not use it because I may or may not include also some fortran code at some point, and as far as I understand the ninja generator of cmake does not support fortran yet (but I admit I did not check for updates in a while).

Comment: which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that! It's version 3.5.2.

Comment: Ugh, why a down vote on the question? I thought it was a legitimate one. If I forgot to add details, tags or was not compliant with SO rules, consider leaving a comment to help me improve next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you define your own target, you can assign more cores to the build process for the target `my_target`, directly inside your `CMakeLists.txt`.
You can include the Cmake module `ProcessCount` to determine the number of cores in your machine and then use this for a parallel build.

```
include(ProcessorCount)
ProcessorCount(N)
if(NOT N EQUAL 0)
  # given that cores != 0 you could modify
  # math(EXPR N "${N}+1")  # modify (increment/decrement) N at your will, in this case, just incrementing N by one
  set(JOBS_IN_PARALLEL -j${N})
endif(NOT N EQUAL 0)
```

and when you define your custom target have something like the following:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(my_target 
                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} ${JOBS_IN_PARALLEL} -f Makefile.custom
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

by the way, I don't think there's the need for you to include also `CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL` among the `COMMAND`s in your target.
I believe that instead of modifying the lines as above, you could call

```
make -j8 my_target
```

and it might start 8 jobs (just an example) without modifying the `CMakeLists.txt`, but I cannot guarantee this works having defined the COMMAND the way you have, just try if that's enough.
For the second point, I cannot think right now of a "cleaner" way.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean I should write 'make' directly instead of using `${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}`? I thought using the cmake variable makes the build system a little more portable, no?

Comment: It's two different things. `${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}` is used inside `CMakeLists.txt` and you should keep it that way. The command `make my_target` you use in the command line to trigger the the build of the custom target .