# include custom makefile in cmake

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I have a cmake project with the typical `build` folder setup.  I would like to instruct cmake to append this line anywhere into its generated Makefile:

```
../make_include/my_stuff.defs
```

I imagine I could tail this onto the Makefile myself, but I feel like that would cause it to continually be marked as dirty and rebuild.  Any help here?

I have seen solutions ([How to get CMake to use existing Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346849/how-to-get-cmake-to-use-existing-makefile)) which use an external project command but I would like something more simple / dumb then that.

Comment: In CMake you cannot use low-level Makefile features, like defining and using makefile variables. The same is true for including make scripts into generated Makefiles. If some part of your project already has a makefile-based builder, it is simpler to use external project for it.

Comment: I undestand, but if I can simply include this file, then I can merge my own commands as long as I make sure there is no conflict.  This seems way more simple to me.